# Comment traduire le mot « antibarbarus » en français ?

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, demande-de-mot, allemand

En [anglais](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/antibarbarus) et en allemand, un *antibarbarus* est un ouvrage qui rassemble les locutions, structures, etc. à éviter lorsque l'on écrit dans une langue donnée.

Comment traduire ce terme en français (et non pas seulement l'emprunter) ?

Answer (score 3):

Ce type d'ouvrage peut être appelé ***Recueil/dictionnaire de [barbarismes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarisme) et [solécismes](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sol%C3%A9cisme)***.

Si la place ne manque pas, on peut même, comme Jean-Noël Blondin, nommer [son ouvrage](https://www.eyrolles.com/Loisirs/Livre/manuel-de-nbsp-la-nbsp-purete-du-nbsp-langage-nbsp-ou-nbsp-recueil-alphabetique-du-nbsp-corrige-nbsp-des-nbsp-barbarismes-des-nbsp-neologismes-nbsp-par-nbsp-j-nbsp-n-blondin-edition-de-1823--8264738236052/) :

> *Manuel de la pureté du langage ou recueil alphabétique du corrigé des barbarismes, des néologismes, des locutions vicieuses et des expressions impropres employées journellement à la tribune, au théâtre et dans la société, par les personnes même qui se piquent de parler et d'écrire avec le plus de perfection la langue française.*
> (1823)
> :-)